# “terminal-notifier” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, terminal

After installing node and Laravel in my new MacOs M1 Chip, when I run `npm run watch`

I get “terminal-notifier” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified on my Laravel project.

What I have done was to install `npm i node-notifier` and that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by opening **System Preferences[image]** then **Security and Privacy**

After App Store and identified developers on the Allow apps downloaded from:

There was an option to allow **terminal notifier**

N/B: Since I have already activated it, it's no longer on the image above

After activating that option, it solved the problem for me.

I hope this helps someone